# checking words in a column of data frame if they exist in another list to create another column based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['read book','cat eats meat','dog barks over the stanger','cow devoted to feed human kind'],'col2':[1,2,3,4]})
```

Split the sentence into words.

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].str.split()`
```

Lists:

```
list1 = ['cow','cat','read'] 
list2 = ['work','barks']
list3 = ['eats','book','devoted','over']
```

Now what I want is that if any word in the ith row of `col3` exists in `list1`, put `'name'` in that ith row but new column called 'col4';
The same way if exists in `list2`, put `'action'` in that row of `col4`;
If in `list3`, put `'mixed'` in `col4`. Thus, multiple values can exist in the same entry

I tried only for the first list, `list1` as follows:

```
df['col4'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x:[word for word in df['col3'] if any(word) in list1])
```

It gives me an empty column.

Comment: This doesn't seem too hard, but the way your formatted the question makes it near impossible

Answer (score 0):

The problem gets much easier, if you use `set` instead of list:

```
list1 = set(['cow','cat','read'])
list2 = set(['work','barks'])
list3 = set(['eats','book','devoted','over'])
```

Then you can use the `intersection` method and combine it with `itertools compress`:

```py
from itertools import compress

df['col4'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x: list(compress(l, \
[any(set(x).intersection(list1)), any(set(x).intersection(list2)), \
any(set(x).intersection(list3))])))
```

Really not the most readable code, you could of course also do it with a proper function:

```
def get_type(l):
    types = []
    if set(l).intersection(list1):
        types.append('name')
    if set(l).intersection(list2):
        types.append('action')
    if set(l).intersection(list3):
        types.append('mixed')
    return types

df['col5'] = df['col3'].apply(get_type)
```

Both methods return the same:

```
                             col1  col2                                   col3             col4
0                       read book     1                           [read, book]    [name, mixed]
1                   cat eats meat     2                      [cat, eats, meat]    [name, mixed]
2      dog barks over the stanger     3       [dog, barks, over, the, stanger]  [action, mixed]
3  cow devoted to feed human kind     4  [cow, devoted, to, feed, human, kind]    [name, mixed]
```